# How to modify imgViewer jquery plugin for zooming to cursor on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

The plugin imgViewer https://github.com/waynegm/imgViewer/ doesn`t have an option for zooming to cursor while scrolling. How to modify the plugin, so it will zoom not only to the center but to cursor position on scroll?

I have tried to use all methods, which available in the plugin. Method imgToView returns necessary coordinates but related to original image size. How can I calculate x and y coordinates when the picture is zoomed?

```
zimg.on("mousewheel", function(ev) {
    var deltaY = 0;
    ev.preventDefault();
    var delta = ev.deltaY ;
    self.options.zoom += delta * self.options.zoomStep;

    var $img = $(self.img),
        width = $img.width() ,
        height = $img.height(),
        bgPosX = bgPosY = 0;

    var bgWidth = bgWidthZoomed = width * self.options.zoom;
    var bgHeight = bgHeightZoomed = height * self.options.zoom;


    var cursorToImg = self.cursorToImg( ev.pageX, ev.pageY);
    var getView = self.getView();
    var imgToView = self.imgToView( cursorToImg.x, cursorToImg.y);

    self.vCenter.x = imgToView.x
    self.vCenter.y = imgToView.y

    self.update();
});
```